# count items in array except value that equal to -1

Tags: c#, .net, linq, count, linq-to-entities

I have this LINQ to entity:

```
int siteNumbers = g.Select(x => x.siteId).ToArray().Distinct().Count()
```

For example:

When `x.siteId` is `-1` I don't want the value to be counted,i.e I want to count only values that not equal to `-1`.

when `x:[1,2,6,-1]` then `siteNumbers` value is 3.

when `x:[-1]` then `siteNumbers` value is 0.

What do I have to change in query above to implement it?

Comment: ToArray should not be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) clause in `LINQ`:

```
int siteNumbers = g.Where(x => x.siteId != -1)
                   .Select(x => x.siteId)
                   .Distinct()
                   .Count();
```

You can also remove the `.ToArray()` as it is redudant.

Working example:
https://ideone.com/LvOe0i

Answer (score 2):

Use `Where` to filter the result

```
int siteNumbers = g.Where(x => x.siteId != -1)
                   .Select(x => x.siteId)
                   .Distinct()
                   .Count();
```

Also calling `ToArray` might not be necessary since `siteId` is integral and SQL knows who to compare them and get distinct values.

you can also add a condition to `Count`

```
int siteNumbers = g.Select(x => x.siteId)
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToArray() 
                   .Count(x => x != -1);
```

you should call `ToArray` since `Count` overload with predicate is not supported by linq to entities

Comment: Count that takes predicate is not supported in linq to entities. take a look at here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738550%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: fixed @M.kazemAkhgary

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Where statement before Select statement like that:

```
int siteNumbers = g.Where(x => x.siteId != -1).Select(x => x.siteId).ToArray().Distinct().Count()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `where` clause in your query to filter out data with `siteId == -1`

```
int siteNumbers = g.Where(f => f.siteId != -1)
                   .Select(x => x.siteId)
                   .Distinct()
                   .Count();
```

Also notice, you do not need a `ToArray()` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int siteNumbers = g.Select(x=>x.siteId).Where(i => i != -1).Distinct().Count()
```